# Betta fish question

Tags: behavior, health, fish, diet, betta

My betta fish does not want to eat and has developed a discoloration under his chin. He is acting sick. Can someone help? Attached is a picture. [image]

Comment: Welcome to Pets Stack Exchange. To give you a good answer to your question we'll need more details otherwise people will have to guess. Please could you edit your question to include age, environment (tank, water temperature etc) and any water parameter readings you can get. You may wish to read [ask] and look at our [list of betta questions](https://pets.stackexchange.com/search?q=betta+%5Bfish%5D+is%3Aq) in case that answers yours.

Answer (score 1):

Its really hard to tell but it could be a fungal infection. If this is the case, all fish in the tank need to be treated as well.

To do this you would want to do a full water change and treating the water with a fungus eliminator( I'm sure you could find one at the petstore). You should do this process every three days until the symptoms are gone, than use bettafix or something stronger to zap the water the kill any remnants.

If this is ich ( which looks like little white spots all over the body) than all fish in the tank should be treated with ich medication.

Like I said in the beginning it it hard to tell but these are two possibilities, I hope it helped !

Comment: Welcome to Pets Stack Exchange :) Could you explain why you would want to do a complete water change? I've never found that to be necessary and would normally stress the fish out more than doing a larger partial water change.